# How to extract a text from Python response , the response format is text/html

Tags: python

I am using Python request module and for an API execution, the response is coming in text/html format. I need to extract a particular text from the response.

```
{'Cache-Control': 'must-revalidate', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Date': 'Thu, 16 May 2019 01:57:47 GMT', 'Expires': 'Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Set-Cookie': 'targetValue-fox=a%3X4%3F%7vu%4t0%3Bs%3A32%3A%34242342jkjk2342342kj42%22%3G%9K; expires=Thu, 16-May-2019 03:57:47 GMT;'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

I need to extract the value coming for `Set-Cookie`. Please let me know how can we do it.

Comment: `response['Set-Cookie']`...?

Comment: It might be `response.get("Set-Cookie")` ?

Comment: Are these the headers of the response?

Comment: You would want to use `dict.get` to get that element. check my answer below @wanderors :)

Answer (score 0):

From the content of the dictionary, the actually look like headers, if they are, use `req.headers` to get them in a dictionary

```
import requests
req = requests.get(.....)
resp = req.headers
```

Then you can extract the value for the key `Set-Cookie` from the `resp` dictionary

```
print(resp.get("Set-Cookie"))
```